# ext-all.css file in Extjs 5

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs5

Using **extjs4.x** there is an e**xt-all.css** file which can be found at this location :

> ext-4.X --> resources --> css --> ext-all.css

It initially just points to a look and feel :

```
@import '../ext-theme-gray/ext-theme-gray-all.css';
```

We then customize it with our own custom CSS, such as icons etc.

```
@import '../ext-theme-gray/ext-theme-gray-all.css';

.ico-outlet {
    background-image :url('../../../../../img/bank-icon.png') !important;
}
```

This is the standard way of adding CSS customizations (..i think)

..

My question is: *Where can i find this file in ExtJS-5? Or what is the equivalent?*

Comment: ext\packages\ext-theme-gray\build\resources - if you are looking for gray

Answer (score 6):

It's mentioned in the [upgrade guide](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/guides/upgrades_migrations/extjs_upgrade_guide.html#upgrades_migrations-_-extjs_upgrade_guide_-__theme_js____theme_css):

> The compiled theme files are now present in the following folder off the root of the distribution:
>
> ```
> packages/{theme}/build/resources/{theme}-all(-rtl)(-debug).css
> ```